# В произвольном тексте подсчитать частоту встречаемости букв

Tags: javascript

В произвольном тексте подсчитать частоту встречаемости букв в нём. Знаки препинания, пробелы, цифры не учитывать. Программа должна выводить все буквы алфавита в порядке уменьшения частоты их встречаемости. Каждая буква должна быть распечатана один раз. Если какие-то буквы встречаются одинаковое число раз, то они выводятся в алфавитном порядке.

> *Исходные данные* Текст длиной не менее 200 символов. Текст может
> содержать большие и маленькие буквы,
> цифры, знаки препинания, пробелы,
> переводы строк, кавычки.
> Гарантируется, что все тексты,
> использованные в качестве тестов к
> задаче, являются литературными
> текстами на английском или русском
> языках.
>
> *Результат* Таблица частот букв текста в
> виде «буква частота_встречаемости»,
> разделённые пробелами.

Пример
исходные данные
batat:)
результат
a 2
t 2
b 1

Comment: да, тут проблема не в javascript'е, а в алгоритме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала надо удалить все пробельные символы и знаки препинания, потом пройти циклом по строке и сделать объект вида `symbs[letter]=nums`, из полученного составить массив вида symbs[n]={letter: nums} и отсортировать его. в результате должно получиться что-то типа [{a:3},{b:3},{c:1}]. если надо вывести в таблицу, то сгененрируйте её любым удобным вам способом.

читать:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML

если нужно на русском, то гуглите термины из вышеозначенных статей